# Changing Color of A Single Row in GtkTreeView

Tags: c, gtk3

I have a GtkIter pointing to my row, which contain a char*,
and I want to change the font color of one of my row in my C Gtk application.

To clarify, I am looking for something similar to the channels panel in Xchat.
screenshot below. (left tab).
https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/9/93/Xchat-2.6.4.png

I'm looking for the simplest solution possible that does not throw a "deprecated" warning at complilation.

Comment: Do you really need to use a `Treeview` or would something like a `ListBox` also work for your goal?